# Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHosts can not be resolved in .NET Standard 1.6 class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-standard

I created a .NET Standard 1.6 class library and added the

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHosts` nuget package to it.

When I try now to resolve the namespace with the following code:

```
 var _server = new  TestServer()new WebHostBuilder()
              .UseStartup<Startup>());
 var _client = _server.CreateClient();
```

It just does not find the namespace...

What do I wrong?

Comment: Did you mean [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost/) (singular)?

Comment: You may be running into issues with versions...
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost looks to require .NET Core 2.0 (which has not officially been released yet)
.NET Standard 1.6 only supports .NET Core 1.0
https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes was a typo...

Comment: @JasonH If it is true what you say, why do they make this public 3 month ago: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing , In the sample code is a xproj file used which is obsolete and for sure not Standard 2.0! HOW then can I use this TestServer class to integration test my endpoints?

Comment: @Elisabeth First I was looking at the .NET Standard 2.0 release of Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost which is in preview and shows a dependency on .NETCoreApp2.0 which is not 'official yet'  If I drop down to the 1.1.2 version it does show a dependency on .NETStandard1.3.  I agree that it should work with a .NET Standard 1.6 for backwards compatibility but I have seen issues with this too.  Try lowering your .NET Standard to 1.3 and see if you can find the namespace.

Comment: I can`t make it low to 1.3 because NUnit - which is added to that class library - wants Standard 1.6+ !

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` NuGet package to get the `WebHostBuilder` - and a custom Startup class - for this code snippet to work.

Comment: I tried adding the *.Hosting nuget but it does not because my class library where I add the Hosting nuget references the API project which is .NET 4.62 framework. Whats the way out of that dll... no dependency hell?